# How to find the elicit slot id for a dialog delegate

Tags: json, model, command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to Alexa development using ask cli, and I ran into a problem when I was going through the dialog-delegate-starter. In the json model, there is a field called elicitation, and it has the value "Elicit.Slot.251925459829.983270759031", which seems to be some sort of auto generated id. I'm imagining creating my own dialog intents, and having to fill this out manually. How is this id generated, and where does one find it?

```
"dialog": {
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "factIntent",
          "confirmationRequired": false,
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "city",
              "type": "cityName",
              "elicitationRequired": true,
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "prompts": {
                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.251925459829.983270759031"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to fill those in manually. Even if you use "manual delegation" you'll have those available. I'm not sure what you need them for, but there's a way to get them.

Maybe this will help: https://developer.amazon.com/es-mx/docs/custom-skills/delegate-dialog-to-alexa.html